# Checking this Big O Analysis

Tags: java, big-o

I'm trying to learn Big O analysis, and I was wondering if someone could let me know if I'm doing it right with these two examples (and if I'm not, where did I go wrong?). I got the first one to be O(N^2) and the second to be O(N). My breakdown of how I got them is in the code below.

First example

```
public void sort(Integer[] v) {
    //O(1)
    if(v.length == 0)
        return;
    //O(N)*O(N)*O(1)
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < v.length; ++j )
        {
            if(v[j].compareTo(v[i]) < 0)
            {
                Integer temp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = v[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second example

```
public void sort(Integer[] v){
    TreeSet<Integer> t = new TreeSet<>();
    //O(N)
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); ++i)
    {
        t.add(v[i]);
    }

    int i = 0;
    //O(N)
    for(Integer value : temp)
    {
        v[i++] = v;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Adding items to a `TreeSet` is not O(1), so the first loop in the second sort is not O(N).

Comment: What is the big o of add items to a tree set?

Comment: Logarithmic in the number of items the set already contains.

Comment: In what language is `for(Integer value : temp)` a valid `for` loop counter?

Comment: You are right, I stand corrected.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks. That's a syntax I haven't seen before  (obviously I'm not a Java coder). :-)

Comment: So then the second example would be O(log(n))?

Comment: O(n log(n)), because you're doing a log(n) operation n times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - the first is `O(N^2)` because you have one loop nested inside another, and the length of each depends on the input `v`. If `v` has length 2, you'll run those swaps 4 times. If `v` has length 8, they will execute 64 times.

<strike>The second is `O(N)` because you have iterate over your input, and your loop contain any iterative or expensive operations.</strike> The second is actually O(n log(n)) - see comments on the original post.

Comment: The second routine is not O(N).

Comment: Oops, I mistook it for a HashSet. Not that that would have done any sorting. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is O(N^2), **you are right**.

Your second example is not O(N), so you **are not** right.

It is O(N) * O(log N) + O(N)

O(N) first loop

O(log N) insert into set

O(N) second loop

Finally you have O(N * log N + N), take the higher value, so answer is **O(N*log N)**

**Edited**

By the way, Big O notation does not depend of programming language

[It could helps](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/)